DocuSign Admin Consent Auth Flow
I'm working on an integration with DocuSign in the form of an external-app so that I can from my app perform API actions on behalf of my users.
I am interested in implementing the Admin Consent flow so that one user in my customers' account will have to go through the auth process.
My POC status is this:
I have a demo account that serves as the host for the integration app (holds the integration and secret keys).
I have another account that simulates my customer account. In this account I defined an organization, made a domain claim and added 2 users with an email that matches the domain.
I performed the admin consent process through one of the users who is defined as admin so that I got to the point where I receive the code and turn it into an access token. In the response of that request I received the id_token field. After I decoded it I got a list of fields but the coid field was not part of them.
What am I missing here?
And is it really recommended to do this process and not simply ask for consent from each user individually?
It's just that my product manager is very pushing for me to implement the Admin Consent to make it easier for our users to use the integration I'm developing.

Can you make any API calls with the token you obtained? the auth token? forget for a second about the coid, there are other ways to get that information. Can you proceed with this token on behalf of the other account?

Yes, I can make API calls based on the access-token Im getting but those calls will be on behalf the user (admin user) who consented to my integration, isn't it?

yes, but what you can do is make an API call to get list of all accounts, all users etc. and then you can impersonate any user once you have their userID

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/usermanagement/users/getusers/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/organization/organization/getorganizations/

So assuming I have a userId that I'd like to use to invoke a certain API - for that matter createEnvelope, how can I do that?

You know how to get an access token using JWT? That's how. During the process you have an option to select the userID. I would suggest you use an SDK for the lang you use. I would further suggest you download our JWT quickstart to see how it works.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/
